# Google Colab not detecting GPU with 'sudo'

Tags: gpu, google-colaboratory, nvidia

I've been using Google Colab to produce Blender renders for a few months, but today my scripts stopped working without any changes. I run my scripts with `sudo` and for whatever reason Google Colab is not giving GPU access to commands run with `sudo`.

This is the output for `nvidia-smi`:

```
/content# nvidia-smi
Fri Jun  3 13:46:21 2022       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 460.32.03    Driver Version: 460.32.03    CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla T4            Off  | 00000000:00:04.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   40C    P8     9W /  70W |      0MiB / 15109MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But the same command throws an error if run with `sudo`:

```
/content# sudo nvidia-smi
Failed to initialize NVML: Driver/library version mismatch
```

`sudo` is important for me because my Blender commands, for whatever reason, don't work without sudo.

```
/content# ./blender-3.1.0-linux-x64/blender -b --python-console -noaudio
src/tcmalloc.cc:283] Attempt to free invalid pointer 0x7fe46122b000 
Aborted (core dumped)
```